The wp-admin url for each site does not work on WordPress multisite
I'm having some trouble while trying to access the admin area of each site in a WordPress multisite. I have the following settings in wp-config.php
define('WP_SITEURL','https://web.mydomain.com');
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] = DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE;
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE;
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE;
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE',true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'web.mydomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

This is the code in my .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

The problem I'm having is when I try to enter the admin area of any site:
https://web.mydomain.com/anysite/wp-admin/index.php
I'm being redirected to the following url, and get a blank page (nothing happens)
https://web.mydomain.com/anysite/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.mydomain.com%2Fanysite%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
This is the virtualhost configuration:
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /mnt/data/www/web
        ServerName web.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias web.mydomain.com
        <Directory "/mnt/data/www/web">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_web.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_web.log combined
</VirtualHost>

I've tried with any .htaccess sample found on internet/github/forums/etc. (even htaccess sampe code in wordpress docs page). I've also renamed plugins folder, erased cache, cookies, etc. without luck.
I'm able to login to the main WordPress area using https://web.mydomain.com/wp-admin/index.php but each site's administrator cannot login using their respective wp-admin url...
Thanks for any ideas you may have to fix this

what's the reason behind the lines assigning values to $_SERVER? That's unusual and not needed on most servers, have you tried without it? Especially when you're assigning them a value that hasn't been defined yet since it's happening before the define statements. Remember PHP code is executed line by line from top to bottom

Also, SERVER_ADDR and REMOTE_ADDR are normally IP addresses, not domain names. And they are not normally the same value either.

@TomJNowell I've put those lines to fix something I don't remember now. Just commented those but nothing solved

@MrWhite just commented those temporarily but didn't help
